# Show Current Date Time in field in alpaca automatically

Tags: alpacajs

I am using alpaca framework. I have date time type, when I click on it only I can able to select the DateTime, I want this to be filled automatically with current date time when it gets focus or when page loaded.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "data" object in alpaca config to set the date field default value to current date:

`"data": { "myDateField": new Date() // or you can use moment } }`

You can also set the date in the postRender function like this:

```
"postRender": function(control) {
   var date = control.childrenByPropertyId["date"];
   var currentDateTime = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
   date.setValue(currentDateTime);
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/dqrrdeuy/) for that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Where should I need to add "data", in the options or in the schema, because I have separated the options and schema

Comment: no you just use it like options and schema, in the first level of your config.